# Not getting customfield__c value after record insert

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I am inserting a custom object record by below code:

```
customobject__c ccc=new customobject__c();
ccc.existingfield1=some value
ccc.existingfield2=some value
insert ccc;
```

After insert, I am not getting **existingfield3** (assign by some existing logic) value in log:

```
system.debug(ccc.existingfield3); //coming null
```

If I query with the `ccc.Id` then I am getting existingfield3 field value in the same apex after insert.

When I am going to the newly inserted record then in record level value is there.

Can anybody let me know what can be the cause?

Answer (score 3):

DML operations do not update anything other than the `Id` field (for inserts) in your in-memory records. Only the fields you set will have values; all other fields will not.

You do have to re-query the record to get other fields, or to see updates against the fields you set caused by process automation. There's an example of doing this in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_section.htm) - see the large block of code at the end of the page.

There are also [mechanisms for performing formula updates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Formula.htm) against in-memory records but that's not what you need here, by the look of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but if only id field is getting updated then what about customobject__c ccc=new customobject__c();
ccc.existingfield1=some value
. because when i amchecking with existingfield1 in debug i am getting proper value.

Comment: You already set that value, so you will see that value when you log it out. Your in-memory version of the record doesn't get updated by an `insert` (this sets the `Id`) or `update`. You set a value for `existingfield1`, but you don't for `existingfield3`, so the former will come back with what you set before, and the latter will be null.

Comment: Thanks its pretty much clear now. can you please share any documentation link.

Comment: @Babu if this answered your question, please mark it to set the question as answered for future searchers.